# How can I find the most active branches in a git repo

Tags: git

I have a git repo with many branches. I like to sort the branches based on how active they are. While I can look for the ones that have the most recent commit, I rather find those with the highest number of commits in the past N days and sort them out that way.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `git log | grep -wc commit`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple script running a variety of shell commands.

First, your script will need to parse the name of all the branches. Use

```
git branch
```

to print all branches to stdout.

Then, you will need to get the number of commits for each branch. use

```
git log BRANCH_NAME | grep -wc commit
```

where `BRANCH_NAME` is the name of the branch you are checking the number of commits for.

Then, you simply need to print the max.

A simple python script looks like this:

```
import subprocess

active_branch = "not found"
max_num = 0 

cmd = "git branch --no-color"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = process.communicate()[0].replace("*", "").replace(" ", "").strip().split("\n")

for branch in result:
    cmd = "git log " + branch + " | grep -wc commit"
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    number = int(process.communicate()[0])
    if number > max_num:
        active_branch = branch
        max_num = number

print("%s is the most active branch with %d commits." % (active_branch, max_num))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "git log BRANCH_NAME | grep -wc commit"  shows commits on a branch but also commits on the parent branch. I think it goes all the way to the beginning of the branch and counts everything.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding git. Suppose I start out with one branch, master. I add 5 commits. I then add a new branch, feature. I add 3 commits to feature. At that point, feature has 8 commits. A commit belongs to a branch if it is an ancestor of the head commit for the branch - not only when it was created on that branch.

Comment: Let's say master has 5 commits. You branch "feature" and you have 2 commits on "feature". Meanwhile, master has 5 more commits and at that point you branch off "feature2" and make 1 commit on "feature2". Now the command  git log BRANCH_NAME | grep -wc commit will show these counts:

master 10
feature 7
feature2 11

Looking at these numbers, it seems that feature2 was the most active branch. While in reality, it only had one commit on it.

Comment: ah that gets quite a bit more complicated then since it's not really the way git is designed, you'd need to parse the entire set of git hashes and even then you could get some errors, for example when you rebase a branch, I don't think there's any way to distinguish which branch created it